# Search by many optional parameters in spring data jpa repository

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have tables comment and author. I want to build complex search bar with many optional parameters. I want filter comments with optional author firstname/lastname and some flags like popularity(based on comment rating).

As I dont know how to write it using spring data jpa repository I ve been thinking on writing it as native query with @Query annotation, smth like this should work

```
Select c.* from comment c join author a on a.id = c.author_id
Where (:firstname = '' or (:firstname = a.firstname)) 
And (:lastname = '' or (:lastname = a.lastname))
And (:popular = false or (c.rating > 25))
```

Is there option to write it using spring data jpa?

In future I plan to add more parameters and pagination for example. Using spring it would be like 1 minute with sql query I will lost few hours.

Is there are some best practices in such cases?

Comment: As I think, this is not that much complex. Provide required entity classes, need to seethe relationship between those classes

Comment: It will be complex when in future I will add there like 10more conditions. Spring method will be then like 100characters or more. My domain is not so intuitive so I switched to comment/author. So lets assume that comment can have many authors(stupid yes). Comment have field authors with @OneToMany relation I will change code later on

Answer (score 12):

I suggest to use `JpaSpecificationExecutor` repository method `findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)`. This solution allows you to extend the parameters list using the same repository and service API

**Entities:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    String firstname ;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    String lastname ;

    // getters, setters, equals, hashcode, toString ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    Author author;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    Integer rating;

    // getters, setters, equals, hashcode, toString ...
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface CommentRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Comment> {

}
```

**Specifications:** `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification`

```
public class CommentSpecs {

      /** if firstname == null then specification is ignored */
      public static Specification<Comment> authorFirstnameEquals(String firstname) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> 
             firstname == null ? 
                 builder.conjunction() :
                 builder.equal(root.get("author").get("firstname"), firstname);
      }

      /** if lastname == null then specification is ignored */
      public static Specification<Comment> authorLastnameEquals(String lastname) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> 
             lastname == null ? 
                 builder.conjunction() :
                 builder.equal(root.get("author").get("lastname"), lastname);
      }

      /** if rating == null then specification is ignored */
      public static Specification<Comment> ratingGreaterThan(Integer rating) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> 
             rating == null ? 
                 builder.conjunction() :
                 builder.greaterThan(root.get("rating"), rating);
      }
}
```

**Service method parameters:**

```
public class CommentParameters {

  String authorFirstname;
  String authorLastname;
  Integer rating;

  // getters, setters

}
```

All parameters are nullable. You can set the parameters you need only. If the parameter is null it is ignored by our specifications

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class CommentService {

  @Autowired
  CommentRepository repository;
                
  public List<Comment> getComments(CommentParameters params, Pageable pageable) {

      Specification spec1 = CommentSpecs.authorFirstnameEquals(params.getAuthorFirstname());                                            
      Specification spec2 = CommentSpecs.authorLastnameEquals(params.getAuthorLastname());
      Specification spec3 = CommentSpecs.ratingGreaterThan(params.getRating());

      Specification spec = Specifications.where(spec1).or(spec2).or(spec3);
                                                                    
      return repository.findAll(spec, pageable);

   }
}
```

I have written the code using a text editor, so it needs a revision. But I think the main point is easy to spot

Comment: I will test solution from answer above as there is no so many boiler plate and then i will test yours

Comment: There is no an elegant solution using single text query for a multiple optional parameters search. All static query solutions would be a far more complex to understand, but less maintainable and less readable

Answer (score 0):

You can use either jpa or criteriabuilder, if you prefer to use JPA, you can do this way:

```
@Query("select s from SomeEntity s "
        + "where (s.description is null or s.description = :description) "
        + "and (s.name is null or s.name = :name) "
List<SomeEntity> find(String description, String name);
```

Comment: how to enable  pagination from spring data jpa for your sample?

Comment: Just add to the parameters `Pageable pageable`, kinda like this 
`Page<SomeEntity> find(String description, String name, Pageable pageable);`. 
Jpa will solve the rest

Comment: Yes, it is. No problem