# How to filter an entity by multiple fields using a Spring JPA Repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am writing back-end for renting flat web app and I have no idea how to filter flats from database (ex. rooms available, beds,floor or city). So I have 10 fields , so user can choose all of them in one search to filter flats and I  just to wanted put in JPA repository all fields in one method but when I used only 5 of them it started freezing I couldn't add more fields.When I start to type for example NumberOfRooms it's just froze ,then by typing each letter also freezing.

1.Is there any limit for searching(filtering) fields ?

2.What is another way to do that?( I wanted to put everything in one method and in controller check if user used all filters or not, checking each field for null)

```
List<Flat> findAllByPriceBetweenAndCityAndRentORbuyAndUtilitiesBetweenAndNumberOfBedsBetweenAndNum(FastMoney less,FastMoney greater,String city,Boolean rentORbuy,int util1,int util2,int num1,int num2);
```

Comment: Derived queries can be used for one or two fields only. Such a long method name reduce code readability. For multi-parameters filter you can use `Specification` as repository method parameter. I have answered similar questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240024/search-by-many-optional-parameters-in-spring-data-jpa-repository/58243100#58243100

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here, since your user does not always provide all fields you need to use more Dynamic queries. I recommend Specifications as the best way to achieve it.

You can find more info in official documentation: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Answer (score 17):

### 88-character query method? Please, don't!

Why would you write an 88-character method that's impossible to parse when you can write a nicely formatted multiline JPQL query, using [`Text Blocks`](https://vladmihalcea.com/multiline-string-java-text-blocks/) for extra points?

### Custom Implementations for Spring Data Repositories to the rescue!

If you want to build the query dynamically, use Criteria API. You can even benefit from the type-safe [`Metamodel`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-criteria-metamodel/).

So, here's what you need to do:

1. Go to the [Custom Implementations for Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) section in the Spring Data manual and see how to create a custom repository where you will add the `findFlats` method.
2. Inside the new `findFlats` method use Criteria API to build the query dynamically.

That's it!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, rather than having a "find" method with an endless name (even if it is supported) I'd suggest, to improve the readability, to create a custom query. In addition if you want to speed the performance, you can even populate a DTO from the query in order to avoid mappings from your Jpa Entity to the DTO (basically I'm suggesting to use a Projection)

Check how to do it here https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score -1):

You may also simply use a library like this one, which lets you build dynamic filters (supports logical operators, comparators, enums, dates, booleans, joins, functions, and much more): https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

Example query:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**

Usage:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/search")
public List<Entity> search(@EntityFilter Specification<Entity> spec, Pageable page) {
  return repo.findAll(spec, page);
}
```

Don't forget the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.turkraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-filter</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

You may also check rsql, although it's a bit outdated now https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser