# Springboot dynamic query with optional parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In the below I can have the `modifedDate` as null some times. at that time it is throwing error as
"could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"

How can I get data even the `modifiedDate` is null. Some time the date will be coming.
How do this ?

I want the below Query method return data always

1. return based on adminStatus if  modifiedDate is null.
2. return based on adminStatus and modifiedDate. if modifiedDate is not null.

we can do by building a dynamic query and executing with entity Manager. but I want with repository.

```
@Repository
public interface AdminRepository extends JpaRepository<AdminEntity, Long> {

@Query(
     value="SELECT * from admin_entity where status=:adminStatus and modified_tsz>=:modifedDate:", 
    nativeQuery=true)
  List<AdminEntity> getAdmins(String adminStatus, Date modifedDate)
}
```

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728843/spring-data-optional-parameter-in-query-method

Comment: I have answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240024/search-by-many-optional-parameters-in-spring-data-jpa-repository/58243100#58243100

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Repository
public interface AdminRepository extends JpaRepository<AdminEntity, Long> {

@Query(
     value="SELECT * from admin_entity where status=:adminStatus
           AND  (modified_tsz>=:modifedDate OR :modifedDate is null)", 
    nativeQuery=true)
  List<AdminEntity> getAdmins(String adminStatus, Date modifedDate)
}
```

Comment: after this , i have got the another error. database is postgres with dates as timestamp with timezone.
error operator does not exist timestamp with time zone >= bytea

this is the error.

Comment: The error now relies on the datatype of your date. Does your previous code work when modifedDate isn't null ?

Comment: i have changed code:

this is the error: *****
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to timestamp with time zone.***

    ******CHANGED     CODE:     + "   AND (cast(:modifiedDate as timestamptz ) IS NULL OR ie.modified_tsz >= :modifiedDate)"