# Using SQL AND only when the value is not null

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Postgres. A filter query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Entity E
WHERE E.field1 = ?
AND E.field2 = ?
AND E.field3 = ?
AND E.field4 = IN (?field4[])
```

`?field1` and `?field2` are mandatory fields so they will be present always. `?field3` and `?field4` are optional. I would like to use `AND E.field3 = ?` & `AND E.field4 = IN (?field4[])` only when the value of `?field3` and `?field4[]` is present, and ignore otherwise

Comment: when field3 adn 4 doesnt have any value pls pass some value like  'default_val' and then try this - `SELECT * FROM Entity E
WHERE E.field1 = ?
AND E.field2 = ?
AND (E.field3 = ? OR E.field3 = 'default_val')
AND (E.field4 = IN (?field4[]) OR E.field4 = 'default_val')`

Comment: You can use `JpaSpecificationExecutor` repository method `findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)`. This solution allows you to extend the parameters list using the same repository and service API. I have answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240024/search-by-many-optional-parameters-in-spring-data-jpa-repository/58243100#58243100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` statement in `where` clause like below

```
SELECT * FROM Entity E
WHERE 
CASE WHEN E.field3 IS NOT NULL and E.field4 IS NOT NULL THEN
E.field1 = ?
AND E.field2 = ?
AND E.field3 = ?
AND E.field4 IN (?field4[])
ELSE
E.field1 = ?
AND E.field2 = ?
END
```

Comment: NULL, NOT NULL these checks I have to apply on the parameters that I am passing, not on the existing column values

Comment: You want to check the value of parameter or column? if you want to compare it with values you are passing, then simply replace `E.field3` with `?field3` and `E.field4` with `?field4` in `case when`