# Hibernate - Query becomes slow when I want to skip condition

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following sample query that terminates in < 0.5 second and returns data via Hibernate:

```
Query qry = em.createQuery(
              "select e from Example e where e.ids in :ids ")
              .setParameter("ids", ids); // List<String> ids
```

Since the list can be null or empty, I included the following trivial condition check that terminates just as quickly on the database side:

```
Query qry = em.createQuery(
              "select e from Example e where (:idFilterUsed = false OR e.ids in :ids ) ")
              .setParameter("ids", ids) // List<String> 
              .setParameter("idFilterUsed", idFilterUsed); // boolean
```

Even if the lower query should seem to have only one small trivial condition more, the query and mapping takes between 12 and 20 seconds instead of < 0.5s !

I can not explain what I have already done and what has not helped me :

- using .createNativeQuery and parsing the result in Example.class
- using an integer (0/1) instead of a boolean parameter
- Changing the order within the OR condition

Anybody have an idea what it could be or are there alternatives to throw out such IN queries should a condition be present? Many of my queries need several such condition checks.

The queries run on an Oracle 12g Database and im using Hibernate 5.4.27.

edit: To avoid misunderstandings -> **the query has this extreme performance loss IF the input list (ids) is filled with at least one ID** and `idFilterUser = true`. It is logical that the query is slow when the list is empty, but practically this got no influence because there are more conditions attached to it.

Comment: The bad performance is due to the fact that you load all contents of a table if the id list is empty, so the database has to do a full table scan and transfer all the data over the network so that Hibernate can then materialize objects from that. You should put a limit on the amount of data to fetch e.g. `.setMaxResults(10)`

Comment: Hey Christian, thx for the reply. if the id list is empty, idFilterUsed is false by design. Doesn't the OR condition then terminate before the IN statement? On database side this seems to be the case, at least the query time tells me so.

Comment: Right `idFilterUsed` is `false` and thus the query then returns all rows. This is the cause for the bad performance.

Comment: u r right, but i got the problem aswell, when `idFilterUsed = true` (and :ids is filled with even one (!) single id), which rly makes no sense for me at all. The problem I am describing relates to queries that return few results (rowsize < 5) both using Hibernate and on the database itself, but take much longer with Hibernate in terms of time (factor 10!).

Comment: I guess you are missing an index and when you try executing it through your SQL editor you are lucky and the data is still in the page cache of the database, so that is faster.

Comment: but does this explain why my query is fast when I remove the OR statement in HQL and only check the IN clause? The ID column that is checked has 100% an index on it.

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue is without more information. Maybe you can share the query execution plan so we can see that the index really is used?

Answer (score 1):

The clause `:idFilterUsed = false` has nothing to do with the database.

I suggest two appropriate options to skip condition:

**1.** For one optional parameter

```
if(idFilterUsed) {
   qry = em.createQuery(
                  "select e from Example e where e.ids in :ids")
                  .setParameter("ids", ids);
} else {
   qry = em.createQuery("select e from Example e");
}
```

**2.** For multiple optional parameters use `Criteria API` or **Spring** [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html).

```
public class ExampleSpecification {

    public static Specification<Example> idIn(List<Long> ids, boolean idFilterUsed) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            if (!idFilterUsed) {
                return builder.conjunction();
            }
    
            return root.get("ids").in(ids);
        };
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface ExampleRepository
        extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<Example> {
}
```

---

```
List<Long> ids = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 5L);
boolean idFilterUsed = false;

exampleRepository.findAll(ExampleSpecification.idIn(ids, idFilterUsed));
```

Look an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240024/search-by-many-optional-parameters-in-spring-data-jpa-repository/58243100#58243100)